# Postgres Sorting of concat(date,string)

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, sorting

I was wondering how does postgres sort the following kind of lists

1. 2021-10-18 15:12:09apple
2. 2021-10-18 12:10:09boy
3. 2021-10-18 11:12:15stack

I tried in postgres and it resulted in the following order

```
with temp_table(a) as (
values ('2021-10-18 15:12:09apple'),
  ('2021-10-18 12:10:09boy'),
 ('2021-10-18 11:12:15stack')
) select * from temp_table order by a
```

"2021-10-18 11:12:15stack"
"2021-10-18 12:10:09boy"
"2021-10-18 15:12:09apple"

How does this work ?

Comment: Why does this surprise you? Obviously `2021-10-18 11:12:15` will be sorted _before_ `2021-10-18 12:10:09`

Comment: What is the desired order?

Answer (score 0):

As expected it sorts data as strings (starting from the leftmost character)

So `2021-10-18 11:12:15stack` < `2021-10-18 12:10:09boy` <  `2021-10-18 15:12:09apple`

because, apart from `2021-10-18`  which is common, `11:12` as string is < `12:10` as string and `15:12` as string